# Finished execution of Mail Reports with result: Failure, Error message: is not of type String

Tags: scheduled-job

I have just worked through upgrading from 5.44 to 5.52 on WordPress. It took a few tries, and I had to do it in stages, but seemed to work in the end except that I have an error in my scheduled jobs now. The full text is this:

```
Parameters raw (from db settings): 
instanceId=[ID of report instance] required
format=[csv or print] optional-output CSV or print-friendly HTML, else PDF

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:3:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:10:"instanceId";s:32:"[ID of report instance] required";s:6:"format";s:67:"[csv or print] optional-output CSV or print-friendly HTML, else PDF";}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Mail Reports with result: Failure, Error message:  is not of type String
```

I haven't added any reports to be mailed in a long time. Not even sure there are any. There is, surprisingly, nothing in the CiviCRM log. Any thoughts? It seems almost like placeholder info is being passed, but I'm not sure why or where I would find that happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably always had that scheduled job running with invalid parameters, it's just now showing in the logs because of a change in civi in logging. I would just turn off that job unless you really think there are reports being mailed, but I doubt it was working.

Normally when you enable that job you replace the placeholders in the parameters section with actual values.